# Delay in Text Printing using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timedelay

How can I delay the calling of a function in Angularjs ? 
I have made a simple form with two text boxes saying First Name and Last Name. A submit button is included which concatenates first and last names and displays the full name. I want whenever this submit button is clicked, the full name must be displayed after 5 seconds or something. How can I implement this delay ?

**My HTML code looks like :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="fname"/> <br>
    Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="lname"/><br>
    <button ng-click="clk()" > SUBMIT </button><br>
    Full Name : {{fullName}}
</body>
</html>
```

**My Controller looks like :**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.fname="";
  $scope.lname="";
  $scope.fullName="";

  $scope.clk = function(){
    $scope.fullName = $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname ;
  };

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$timeout` to delay the code execution inside the function.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.fname="";
  $scope.lname="";
  $scope.fullName="";

  $scope.clk = function(){
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.fullName = $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname ;
    },5000)
  };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used `$timeout` from angularJs.

```
$scope.clk = function(){
      $timeout(function(){
       $scope.fullName = $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname ;
      },5000);
  };
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3r14kq1x/1/).